# PebbleSolitaire solution not getting accepted in Kattis (java)

Tags: java, recursion

I received some programming tasks to do to advance to the next step in a job interview. Got all of them accept expect one, description: https://academicwork.kattis.com/problems/pebblesolitaire2 (automated code correctiong software)

While it was a long time since I used recursion, I still thought I came up with a pretty simple and working solution. (Probably not the best one though.) It handles all the "sample inputs" that are presented in the problem description and gives the correct "outputs" as far as I can see. It still got rejected though, and the only clue to the rejection was "On test file 2/7 it failed: Wrong Answer". Without more to go on than that, I really cannot figure out where my code is giving out the wrong answer.

Any suggestions on how to move forward?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PebbleSolitaire {

private static int bestMove;
private static char[] table;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        int i = scan.nextInt();

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            bestMove = 23;
            String a = scan.next();
            table = a.toCharArray();
            char[] testTable = a.toCharArray();
            checkMoves(testTable);
            System.out.println(bestMove);

        }

    }

}

public static void checkMoves(char[] array) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
        if (array[i] == 'o' && array[i + 1] == 'o') {
            if (i + 2 < 23 && array[i + 2] == '-' && i - 1 >= 0 && array[i - 1] == '-') {
                char[] tempArray;
                tempArray = array;
                tempArray[i - 1] = 'o';
                tempArray[i] = '-';
                tempArray[i + 1] = '-';
                checkMoves(tempArray);

                table[i + 2] = 'o';
                table[i] = '-';
                table[i + 1] = '-';
                checkMoves(table);

            }
            if (i + 2 < 23 && array[i + 2] == '-') {
                array[i + 2] = 'o';
                array[i] = '-';
                array[i + 1] = '-';
                checkMoves(array);
            }
            if (i - 1 >= 0 && array[i - 1] == '-') {
                array[i - 1] = 'o';
                array[i] = '-';
                array[i + 1] = '-';
                checkMoves(array);
            }
        }
    }

    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
        if (array[i] == 'o') {
            counter++;

        }
    }

    if (counter < bestMove) {
        bestMove = counter;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if you've figured it out or not.

The problem is that the variables you create for the array refer to the SAME object. so whenever you change any variable (be it `array` or `tempArray`) the value of the *OBJECT* changes. The array variables refer to the same object.